# Are any Greek or Roman gods mentioned by name in the Bible?

Tags: bible, gods

Are any Greek or Roman gods mentioned by name in the Bible?

Also, are any Greek or Roman mythological characters or creatures mentioned in the Bible?

Comment: See also 2 Maccabees 6:2.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, several different Romans and Greek gods are mentioned.  Artemis, Zeus, and Hermes are all **Greek** gods and Ashteroth was known as Astarte or **Aphrodite** to the **Greeks**.

**Artemis** was also known to the **Romans** as **Diana** and **Ashteroth** was known to them as **Venus**.

> When they heard this they were enraged and were crying out, “Great is **Artemis** of the Ephesians!”  Acts 19:28 ESV
>
> Barnabas they called **Zeus**, and Paul, **Hermes**, because he was the chief speaker.  Acts 14:12 ESV
>
> After three months we set sail in a ship that had wintered in the island, a ship of Alexandria, with **the twin gods** as a figurehead.  Acts 28:11 ESV  [This apparently refers to Castor and Pollux.]
>
> For Solomon went after **Ashtoreth** the goddess of the Sidonians, and after Milcom the abomination of the Ammonites.  1 Kings 11:5 ESV

[List of false gods mentioned in the Bible.](http://www.biblegateway.com/resources/dictionary-of-bible-themes/8747-false-gods)

Comment: I think Baal, Ashtoreth and Milcom are not Greek deities.

Comment: @Mawia Indeed, they are not.  I mentioned there were others as well and included those to support the claim.  I have tried to clarify that.  Thank you.

Comment: @Mawia: Have a look at Baal's mythology.  You might be surprised at how closely he resembles Zeus.

Comment: As a quick plug, some scholars think that the Nephilim mentioned in the Old Testament may be the inspiration for some of the pagan gods and demigods that were worshiped throughout history. See [What were the Nephilim, and what role did they play in the Bible beyond just being mentioned?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/16192) for more information.

Comment: Also, if you look at the Septuagint, there is the mention of a few other gods, including Ar(i)es. For example, Judges 8:13 in the LXX: καὶ ἐπέστρεψεν Γεδεων υἱὸς Ιωας ἀπὸ τῆς παρατάξεως ἀπὸ ἐπάνωθεν τῆς παρατάξεως **Αρες**. Aries. You'd have to read the entire LXX to see if there's more. I just happened to notice that particular one on an occasion.

Answer (score -2):

Thanatos, Hades, and Tartarus are mentioned too, though more in relation to the places (though they are anthropomorphized).

Thanatos (Death) is described as the last enemy that is destroyed.

The bible also says that all the "gods" of the Gentiles are in fact demons.

Comment: This answer would be acceptable if you could add references.  See [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/)