# Did the early church believe there were TWO types of descendant from the Nephalim?

Tags: genesis, enoch, giants, seth

The Bible quotes from earlier Books like the Book of Adam & Eve, Book of Seth, Book of Jashur etc; Rabboni Yeshua (Our Lord) read these books too and taught them to the early church without remittance, so we can assume that these books are safe for divine council today and that they will confirm or expound what the Holy Bible informs. So I hope this will be classed as a Christian question and not sanctioned in anyway.

In an early Jewish text (I'm still trying to find it) apparently, two angels are discussing historical and future events. They refer to the giants as "Elephants" (who were wiped out in the deluge) and another "race" as "donkeys". These donkeys where other descendants of Nephalim who were normal human size but had superior intelligence. These apparently are still with us today.

Can you tell me the name of this book? Was someone in Noah's Ark a hybrid? How did giants reappear later if they were exterminated in the flood unless a high science brought them back? or does the bible just not tell us about other expeditions by other pre-flood people who too might have escaped the flood?

**I apologize if my question is not clear, I'm fuzzy minded and this is the first time I have used this site and I've just woken up. Good Morning everyone. **

Comment: Your title doesn't at all match your question. Do you care to clarify what it is you're actually asking? Are you just trying to identify this early Jewish piece of literature?

Comment: I see that now. Yes please help me identify this text, I can find the rest of the answers from there.

Comment: In that case, I think the question is off-topic here. It might, however, be on topic at [Mi Yodeya](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Translations of ancient words for animals are notoriously difficult to translate. Do a search for "unicorns in the bible" as an example.

Answer (score 3):

As far as the Bible is concerned about the Nephilim, it seems quite clear that they are annihilated in the Flood, but somehow they survive. The Flood story starts in Genesis six and seems to indicate that the Nephilim were a major reason for sending it.

> The Nephilim were on the earth in those days—and also afterward—when the sons of God went to the daughters of humans and had children by them. They were the heroes of old, men of renown. [Genesis 6:4](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+6&version=NIV)

As far as I know, the Bible never gives an explanation for how they survived. That they were giants is affirmed in Numbers and other places as well, the story of Goliath being most notable.

> We saw the Nephilim there (the descendants of Anak come from the Nephilim). We seemed like grasshoppers in our own eyes, and we looked the same to them. [Numbers 13:33](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Numbers%2013:33&version=NIV)

Whether these survivors are a separate race or the original Nephilim is not mentioned either. It is hinted, perhaps, that the Nephilim after the Flood were divided into plenty of tribes. Among these were Anakites (perhaps the first that brought about the others), Rephaites (Goliath was one of these and they were also called Emites), and Gittites. There's also the mention of some polydactyl Nephilim, having more than five digits on the hands and feet ([1 Chronicles 20:6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Chronicles%2020:4-8&version=NIV) and [2 Samuel 21:20](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Samuel%2021:15-22&version=NIV)). This is a major indication that there was something genetically different with the Nephilim.

The Nephilim are indeed mentioned and talked about much more in non-canonical books, but I'm not familiar with one that describes them as two races, one before and one after the Flood. If the early Church believed such a thing it was either speculative or based on other, non-Scriptural sources.

I've written an answer that covers pretty much everything the Bible has to say about the Nephilim, but it stops short of extra-Biblical sources, seeing that as off-topic for this site:

[What were the Nephilim, and what role did they play in the Bible beyond just being mentioned?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/16190/3961)