# How were the Nephilim still in existence after the flood?

Tags: exegesis, genesis, nephilim

> The Nephilim were on the earth in those days, and also afterward, when the sons of God came in to the daughters of man and they bore children to them. These were the mighty men who were of old, the men of renown. *(Genesis 6:4)*

The way I understand it is that the Nephilim were around in the days before the flood?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. Yes that passage says they were before the flood. So why are you asking about after the flood?

Comment: I think [my answer here](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/16190/what-were-the-nephilim-and-what-role-did-they-play-in-the-bible-beyond-just-bei/16192#16192) might answer your question. At least, it's an overview about the Nephilim.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is what that verse meant. It says :

> The Nephilim were on the earth in those days, and also afterward,
>   **when**...

This was meant to explain how the Nephilim came to the earth. The **when**  here explains how the Nephilims came :

> *the sons of God came in to the daughters of man and they bore children to them*

So they were not there before but they came as a result of the union between those sons of God (fallen angels) and the daughters of men

Comment: Thank you - yes the "when" explains how they came - the thing that is confusing me is that there are debates that God send the flood because of the acts of the fallen angels - So why then would He send the flood before the Nephilim came - how could they be in existence after the flood, unless there were more fallen angels after the flood as well as before? I know this is not the most important thing to know about the Bible, it's just out of interest sake.

Comment: God did not destroy the earth because of the acts of the fallen angels. He destroyed it because of the act of men who became wicked as a result of fellowshiping with the Nephilim and bearing their children (Gen 6:5). However, I THINK, the fact that God has destroyed the earth did not destroy the Fallen angels who came to have sex with the humans. So I GUESS, they continued in their actions after the flood knowing that after the Sacrifice of Noah God swore that he was no longer going to destroy the eart that way.