# Is the Book of Enoch authentic?

Tags: canon, book-of-enoch

I grew up reading the Holy Bible which portrays God as a loving Father, full of compassion and goodwill for mankind. However, after reading the **Book of Enoch**, I am perplexed at the way heaven and God are portrayed. I was filled with fear and I kept asking myself is this the God Christ reflected while on Earth. My question is that is the **Book of Enoch** canonical?

Comment: Have you looked at [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Enoch)? That discusses this very question.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). About your question, for most Christian denominations and sects, the answer is no, Enoch is not canonical. But according to the [table at the Biblical Canon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_canon#Table) article on Wikipedia, it is canonical in the Orthodox Tewahedo denominations. Meanwhile, for more on what this site is all about, please see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Comment: According to whom? This is opinion-based

Comment: The Book of Enoch is canon in the Ethiopian Orthodox Church. The [Book of Enoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Enoch) was not included in the Christian canon of books in the 4th century and is regarded as Scripture in only the Ethiopian Orthodox Church and the Eritrean Orthodox Church. Why? I think that Tertullian (155-240) holds the key! Have a look [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/46972/25495).

Answer (score 2):

The Old Testament canon for Christians was formally set for all five ancient Church Sees (Rome, Constantinople, Antioch, Alexandria, Jerusalem) at the 7th Ecumenical Council in 787.  This Council ratified the Old Testament canons of the local councils of [Carthage in 397](http://www.bible-researcher.com/carthage.html) and Trullo in 692.  The council of Trullo had ratified the canon specified [Canon LXXXV of the Apostolic Canons](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf214.xvii.iv.html).

In neither these local councils nor in the 7th Ecumenical Council was the Book of Enoch specified as one of the canonical Old Testament books.  The canon that the 7th Ecumenical Council ratified was the combined lists of the two aforementioned local councils:

> - Genesis, Exodus, Leviticus, Numbers, Deuteronomy
> - Joshua, Judges, Ruth
> - Four "Books of Kings", namely 1/2 Samuel and 1/2 Kings
> - Two "books of Paraleipomena", i.e. 1/2 Chronicles
> - Job
> - Psalms
> - Five "books of Solomon": Proverbs, Ecclesiastes, Song of Songs, Wisdom of Solomon, and Wisdom of Sirach (Ecclesiasticus)
> - The books of the 12 Prophets: Hosea, Amos, Micah, Joel, Obadiah, Jonah, Nahum, Habakkuk, Zephaniah, Haggai, Zechariah, Malachi
> - Isaiah, Jeremiah, Ezekiel, Daniel
> - Tobit
> - Judith
> - Esther
> - Two "books of Esdras": Ezra and Nehemiah
> - Three books of Maccabees